# I want to make some angled border View at React Native

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, border, stylesheet

[image: example View]

I want to make View like this, but I can't make angled border T.T I`m not well at css,, please can you help me?
I tried this code.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

export interface CuttedComponentProps {
  cuttedComponentWidth: number;
  cuttedComponentHeight: number;
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  backgroundColor: string;
  zIndex?: number;
  borderBottom?: boolean;
}

class CuttedComponent extends React.Component<CuttedComponentProps> {
  constructor(props: CuttedComponentProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render() {
    const {
      style,
      cuttedComponentWidth,
      cuttedComponentHeight,
      backgroundColor,
      zIndex,
      borderBottom,
      children
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={style}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: borderBottom ? -StyleSheet.hairlineWidth : 0,
            top: borderBottom ? -StyleSheet.hairlineWidth : 0,
            zIndex: zIndex && zIndex + 0.5,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderRightWidth: cuttedComponentHeight,
            borderTopWidth: cuttedComponentWidth,
            borderRightColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopColor: backgroundColor
          }}
        />
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default CuttedComponent;
```

and I tried this code, but it(border) doesn't show at the angled corner.

Comment: https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native this might help

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@raywinarto/diamond-cut-text-area this is a snack I made with the design u requested, hope this gives you an idea of how to make it. A bit tedious but that's usually how it's done, so better to put this in a reusable component on its own and pass the `areaWidth` and `areaHeight` as props.